# How to NOT a helper?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

What is the best way to perform a NOT operation?

For example, here's the javascript

```
Template.mytemplate.helper({
  myhelper : function(){
    return true;
  }
});
```

Now how would I get !myhelper in a template? I've been doing

```
<template name="mytemplate">
  {{#if myhelper}}
  {{else}}
    myhelper is false
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

But there's gotta be a better way. I could create an equality helper and do `{{#if equal myhelper true}}` but that doesn't seem very clean.

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: `if x else y` = `x || y`

Comment: you can create `not` helper and use it like: `{{#if not myhelper}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the [`#unless`](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/#unless) spacebar to get what you want:

```
<template name="mytemplate">
  {{#unless myhelper}}
    myhelper is false
  {{/unless}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just to use a `isNot` in your helper name.

Compare:

```
<template name="mytemplate">
  <!--
    ✓ Easy to read
    – Looks not clean
  -->
  {{#if isActive}}
  {{else}}
    item is not active
  {{/if}}

  <!--
    - Not very easy to read
    ✓ Looks clean
  -->
  {{#unless isActive}}
    item is not active
  {{/unless}}
</template>
```

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({
  isActive: function() {
    return Session.get('isActive');
  },
});
```

VS:

```
<template name="mytemplate">
  <!--
    ✓ Easy to read
    ✓ Looks clean
  -->
  {{#if isNotActive}}
    item is not active
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({
  isNotActive: function() {
    return ! Session.get('isActive');
  }
});
```

Comment: Ugh. I hate a situation where a control mechanism has more switches than it should. What does the `isActive: true, isNotActive: true` state represent?? Each state should be true and valid.

Comment: I'm totally agree with you. Only one helper should exist at the same time `isActive` or `isNotActive`. I added two of them just to show comparison. I was not suggesting to use two helpers at the same time.